# XRay REST API Feature File Import Fails Parsing

Tags: rest, import, jira-xray, feature-file

## Version of Xray

6.5.0
[image]

## Feature File Being Imported - Simplified Version

```
Feature: Something Something CC AllProducts

Scenario: Something With Three Products
    Given billing something is xyz 
    When I make a something something transaction
    Then the database values are xyz
```

## Response

```
{
    "testIssues": [],
    "preConditionIssues": [],
    "message": "Error parsing feature file\n"
}
```

Am I missing tags?

## Documentation Used

https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY500/Importing+Cucumber+Tests+-+REST

## Original Feature File (Redacted)

```
Feature: xxx CC AllProducts

Background:
    Given billing xxx is xxxx
    And xxx method is ttt
    And machine details are
        | MachineId | ActorId    | HwSerial         |
        | 11111     | 1111       | 1111             |

@research
Scenario Outline: TTTTT With Three Products
    Given I have the products
        | ProductCode | ProductValue | UnitCode | QuantityValue |
        | 0           | 100          | 1        | 2             |
        | 1           | 200          | 1        | 1             |
    And generated <CardType> card
    When I make a allProducts WWWWW transaction
    Then the database values are
        | WWW     | QQQ     | YYYY        | QQRR    | BBBB               |
        | 400     | 400     | 1           | <IsEmv> | 2                  |

Examples:
    | CardType | IsEmv  |
    | CON      | True   |
    | CLS      | True   |
```

When this failed parsing, my colleague and I tried to strip it down to the most basic elements, but, as I mentioned, it failed, too.

Using version 2.0 of the API.

## Request Sent From Postman

```
curl --location 'https://jira.MYCOMPANY.com/rest/raven/2.0/import/feature?projectKey=NCS' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRpajpEZWU4MTg4OTE5OSEh' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=1A0E4F9D64EA77D468285A3DE2F26AF3; atlassian.xsrf.token=BFS8-LR8B-Z1EU-6YVL_3c474e4ccb370815dd28576ffde8fa3f390cb5a2_lin' \
--form 'file=@"/D:/adij/Downloads/CC_MultiVend_AllProduct.feature"'
```

Comment: 1. you are using Xray on Jira server/datacenter right (not Xray cloud)? 2. if you're using Xray on Jira server/datacenter, which Xray version do you have installed? 3. Are you submitting the .feature file or .zip with the .feature file?

Comment: 1. Yes, Xray on a regular Jira server.   2. please help me find that info   3. Just a .feature file (one)

Comment: Your .feature file looks fine. I tried it myself.


 curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u username:password -F "file=@a.feature" "https://myserver/rest/raven/2.0/import/feature?projectKey=CALC"

Comment: 2. you need to ask your Jira admin to get that information from Jira administration

Comment: Version 6.5.0 of Xray

Comment: Ok, so you have a recent version of Xray. I used the "Original Feature File (Redacted)" that you provided and the `curl` command I shared, and it worked so pershaps we're not using the same .feature file or there are some strange characters on it not visible to the eye. Can you try the a.feature file that I used? (https://gist.github.com/bitcoder/4eb6124eaacb5f13769fccba34e1f92a) and my curl command? If that still doesn't work out, I would recommend reaching out to Xray support team (https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) so they can diagnose this with you in more detail.

Comment: Thank you, Sérgio.  I'll mark this resolved, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Sérgio's comments to the original post.